# Firing an event handler in IE using VBA

Tags: jquery, vba, internet-explorer

I have found many similar questions but the solutions are all specific to the page being worked with.  I am trying to select a value from a drop down and then fire the event handler to reset the page.  I am not the best at working with HTML and I am unable to figure how to get the page to update after I assign a value to the dropdown menu.  Here is what I have:

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim IECollection As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate "https://www.theocc.com/webapps/historical-volume-query"

    Do While IE.busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set IECollection =IE.Document.getElementsByName("historicalVolumeSearch.reportType")
    i = 0
    While i < IECollection.Length
        If IECollection(i).Name = "historicalVolumeSearch.reportType" Then
            IECollection(i).Value = "PC"
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Wend
```

I can't figure out what to call next from the page source code to make it update.

Thanks.

Comment: Would be easier to use the options outlined on this page: https://www.theocc.com/market-data/batch-processing.jsp

Comment: @TimWilliams Unfortunately the data I need is not easy to extract from the batch reports.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.  I stepped away from this for a few weeks and came back to it and the answer was right in front of me.  I changed my above code to what is below.  Works as I want it to and allows me to store the HTML and scrape out the data that I need.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim IECollection As Object
Dim IECollection2 As Object
Dim IEElement As Object
Dim dt As String

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "https://www.theocc.com/webapps/put-call-ratio"

Do While IE.busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

       For i = 1 To UBound(arrDates) 'an array containing a list of dates
        dt = arrDates(i, 1)
        Set IECollection = IE.Document.getElementsByName("putCallDate")
            IECollection(0).Value = dt
            IECollection(0).Select

        Set IECollection2 = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("form")
            j = 1
            While j < IECollection2.Length
                If IECollection2.Item(j).Name = "commandForm" Then
                    Set IEElement = IECollection2.Item(j)
                    IEElement.submit
                End If
            j = j + 1
            Wend

        Do While IE.busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
      'other code in here that stores the HTML as a string and scrapes out data
      Next i
```